# Rate of return on a loan

Tags: loans, interest-rate, rate-of-return

If I lend you $100 at, say, 10% annual interest for a 3 year term (36 months), your monthly instalment (usual amortization schedule) should be $3 per month for 36 months, for a total of $116, right?

My question is how to back out an effective rate of return if you don't repay in full. E.g. say you only pay $1/month (giving a total repayment of $36) - what is my rate of return (as lender)?

Comment: Depends on  the loan. Loans like that may be "pay interest, pay back capital in 3 years".

Answer (score 2):

With

```
r is the monthly rate
n is the number of months
s is the principal
d is the monthly payment
```

Assuming the annual rate is nominal 10% [compounded monthly](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Effective_interest_rate#Calculation)

```
r = 10/100/12
n = 36
s = 100
```

Using the [ordinary annuity formula](http://financeformulas.net/Annuity_Payment_Formula.html)

```
d = (r (1 + r)^n s)/((1 + r)^n - 1) = 3.22672
```

resulting in a repayment total of `36 * d = $116.16`

Resetting the monthly repayment

```
d = 1
```

Numerically solving the ordinary annuity formula for `r`

```
r = -0.0473652
```

The annual nominal rate is `12 * r = -56.8383 %` compounded monthly

*Annuity formula solution*

[image]

For more information on annuities see [Present & Future Value of Annuities](https://www.investopedia.com/retirement/calculating-present-and-future-value-of-annuities/)